# Having problem in conversion from Recursive solution to DP

Tags: recursion, tree, c++14, binary-tree, dynamic-programming

Given a Binary Tree of size N, find size of the Largest Independent Set(LIS) in it. A subset of all tree nodes is an independent set if there is no edge between any two nodes of the subset. Your task is to complete the function LISS(), which finds the size of the Largest Independent Set.

I came up with this recursive solution.

```
int rec(struct Node *root,bool t)
{
    if(root==NULL)
    return 0;

    if(t==true)
    {
        return max(1+rec(root->left,!t)+rec(root->right,!t),rec(root->left,t)+rec(root->right,t));
    }
    else
    {

        return max(rec(root->left,!t)+rec(root->right,!t),rec(root->left,t)+rec(root->right,t));
    }
}
int LISS(struct Node *root)
{
    int x,y;
    y=rec(root,true);

    return y;
}
```

To solve this problem via DP, I modified the code as follows, but then it gives wrong answer. 
It doesn't even work with Binary tree with distinct elements.

```
map<int,int> mm;
int rec(struct Node *root,bool t)
{
    if(root==NULL)
    return 0;

    if(mm.find(root->data)!=mm.end())
    return mm[root->data];


    if(t==true)
    {
        mm[root->data]=max(1+rec(root->left,!t)+rec(root->right,!t),rec(root->left,t)+rec(root->right,t));
        return mm[root->data];
    }else
    {
        mm[root->data]=max(rec(root->left,!t)+rec(root->right,!t),rec(root->left,t)+rec(root->right,t));
        return mm[root-s>data];
    }
}
int LISS(struct Node *root)
{
    //Code here
    mm={};
    int y=0;

    y=rec(root,true);

    return max(x,y);
}
```

What's the mistake?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two states in your function but you are memoizing only one state. Let's say for root x,

`rec(x,true) = 5` and

`rec(x,false) = 10` .

You calculated the `rec(x, true)` first and saved it in your map "mm" as mm[x] = 5.

So when you are trying to get the value of `rec(x, false)` it is getting the value of `rec(x, true)` which is 5.